# Search and filter data using mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, filter

I am just starting to learn php and mysql, and am creating a project using php and mysql. I am stuck while searching and filtering the data from the database. The search is basically a combined search and filter the data  according to the user inputs.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
public function filterSearch(Request $request){
    $new  =  $request->get('new');
    $used  =  $request->get('used');
    $registered  =  $request->get('registered');
    $make = $request->get('make');
    $model = $request->get('model');
    $price = $request->get('price');
    $city =  $request->get('city');
    $registration = $request->get('firstRegistration');

    $query =  DB::select("SELECT  * FROM ads WHERE vehicleCond LIKE '".$new."' OR vehicleCond LIKE '".$used."' OR vehicleCond LIKE '".$registered."' ");
    $decode =  json_decode(json_encode($query),true);
    $finalArr = array();
    for($i=0; $i<count($decode); $i++){
        if($make || $model || $registration){
            if(($decode[$i]['make'] == $make) || ($decode[$i]['model'] == $model) ||  ($decode[$i]['registration'] == $registration)){
                array_push($finalArr,$decode[$i]);
            }
        }else{
            array_push($finalArr,$decode[$i]);
        }   
    }
    return response()->json(['success'=>$finalArr], 200);

   }
```

The result is not correct...for single selection, it is working fine. When I used the combination, then the result is not correct.

Comment: `LIKE` is for matching patterns. Use `=` for exact matching.

Comment: "Here is my code". OK, what's your question?

Comment: I'm assuming you are using Laravel, as the Query Builder syntax seems familliar.

To be blunt, you need to re-read the Laravel docs, because this is exactly how to NOT use Laravel's Query Builder - Ignoring the fact that your code is wrong, if it were to work, it would be extremely prone to SQL injections.

Comment: @Barmar: Question Updated

Comment: Show us the generated SQL for a case that is failing.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you need your query/filter to be dynamic.

Your html scripts can be follow like below pattern/format:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="filter1" value="new">
<input type="checkbox" name="filter1" value="used">
<input type="checkbox" name="filter1" value="pre-registered">

<select name="filter2" id="">...</select>
<select name="filter3" id="">...</select>
```

and in the Php file you may use some conditions to append the query criterias/filter:

```
$criteria = "";
if($request->get('filter1'))
{
    $criteria .= " AND `filter1` = '".addslashes($request->get('filter1'))."'";
}

if($request->get('filter2'))
{
    $criteria .= " AND `filter2` = '".addslashes($request->get('filter2'))."'";
}

//and so on...

//output
$query =  DB::select("SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE 1 = 1 {$criteria}");
```

Notes:

You might need be cautious on forming **$criteria** as it might still have chance of getting Sql Injection using **DB::select** method, but i believe you can use the same logic to adapt using Laravel Eloquent method.

Comment: What is `addslashes` for?

Comment: Since we're using DB::select, I've added an extra step to prevent SQL Injection. By using addslashes, this function will add \ on the string whenever they detect any quote in the string. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Comment: This is a quite archaic way against SQL injections. `DB::select()` supports prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for your issue

```
    public function filterSearch(Request $request){
        $make = $request->get('make');
        $model = $request->get('model');
        $price = $request->get('price');
        $city =  $request->get('city');
        $registration = $request->get('firstRegistration');
        $searchFields = [
            'new',
            'used',
            'registered'
        ];

        $query =  DB::table('ads')->where(function ($query) use ($searchFields, $request) {
                collect($searchFields)->each(function($field) use($likeCriteria, $query) {
                    $likeCriteria = $request->get($field);
                    if ($likeCriteria === '') {
                        $likeCriteria = '%';
                    }

                    $query->orWhere($field, 'like', '%' . $likeCriteria . '%');
                });
            })->get();

        $decode =  json_decode(json_encode($query),true);
        $finalArr = array();
        for($i=0; $i<count($decode); $i++){
            if($make || $model || $registration){
                if(($decode[$i]['make'] == $make) || ($decode[$i]['model'] == $model) ||  ($decode[$i]['registration'] == $registration)){
                    array_push($finalArr,$decode[$i]);
                }
            }else{
                array_push($finalArr,$decode[$i]);
            }   
        }
        return response()->json(['success'=>$finalArr], 200);
    }
```

- First, move all the variables that you want to search for into array `$searchFields` so we can avoid duplication of code and use clean code.
- Change your DB query so we can use `table` method then `where` with query  function to move all the logic inside of it and also avoid SQL injections.

On this link you can learn more about this : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses

Let me know if you have any question.

Answer (score 0):

I would change this:

```
$new  =  $request->get('new');
$used  =  $request->get('used');
$registered  =  $request->get('registered');
$make = $request->get('make');
$model = $request->get('model');
$price = $request->get('price');
$city =  $request->get('city');
$registration = $request->get('firstRegistration');
```

to this:

```
    $new  =  (empty($request->get('new')) ? "%" : $request->get('new');
    $used  =  (empty($request->get('used')) ? "%" : $request->get('used');
    $registered  =  (empty($request->get('registered')) ? "%" : $request->get('registered');
    $make = (empty($request->get('make')) ? "%" : $request->get('make');
    $model = (empty($request->get('model')) ? "%" : $request->get('model');
    $price = (empty($request->get('price')) ? "%" : $request->get('price');
    $city =  (empty($request->get('city')) ? "%" : $request->get('city');
    $registration = (empty($request->get('firstRegistration')) ? "%" : $request->get('firstRegistration');
```

Answer (score -1):

i would try to store the query to a variable and then add the selection if isset or not empty using ternary condition or ternary if

```
$query=""SELECT  * FROM ads WHERE 1=1 ";
$query.=(isset($new) && $new!='' ? " OR vehicleCond LIKE '%" . $new . "%'" : "");
$query.=(isset($used) && $used!='' ? " OR vehicleCond LIKE '%" . $used. "%'" : "");
$query.=(isset($registered) && $registered!='' ? " OR vehicleCond LIKE '%" . $registered. "%'" : "");
//and so on depends on your selection variables
//after that
$query =  DB::select($query);
```

cheers